# Conditional format Python

Tags: python

How to fix that error?
I use Conditional format in Python.

**My code:**

```py
conditions  = [ 
     table['Lump']  >= 5000 , 
     table['SIP']   >= 3000 , 
     (table['Lump'] >= 5000 & table['SIP'] >= 3000),
     table['SIP'] < 3000] 
]
choices  = [ "Lump", 'SIP','Both','Low' ]
table['Status'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=np.nan)
```

**Error shows:**

```py
 File "<ipython-input-501-03acb2a1fc51>", line 1
     conditions  = [ table['Lump'] >= 5000 , table['SIP'] >= 3000 ,
     (table['Lump']>= 5000 & table['SIP'] >= 3000),table['SIP'] < 3000] 


SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You have unbalanced brackets.

Comment: near the " table ['SIP'] < 3000] ]" you use twice brackets. so it's unbalance brackets used. check your code again.

Answer (score 0):

Remove bracket from right side

```
conditions  = [ table['Lump'] >= 5000 , table['SIP'] >= 3000 , (table['Lump']>= 5000 & table['SIP'] >= 3000),table['SIP'] < 3000]
```